# Edge (or other browser) extension to notify if a site I'm trying to open is already open in another tab and make it quick/easy to switch to that tab

Tags: web-browser

I'm looking for a browser extension (ideally for Edge) that will notify me if I try to load a new tab on a site that is already open.

Too many times my browser tabs fill up with repeated sites - it would be helpful to be notified it's already open and given option to quickly/easily switch to that tab.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has a bunch of extensions like this, e.g. [Clutter Free](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clutter-free-prevent-dupl/iipjdmnoigaobkamfhnojmglcdbnfaaf) that I've used due to integration with The Great Suspender extension and that I can recommend.

It has a lot of features, such as detection of existing duplicates, auto opening of the duplicate if it's found, searching by tab titles, etc.